# COPY file from one server to another

Tags: ssh, cp, scp

I have to get some files from production to DEV server. SCP command gives the timeout.

I do not have ip and I connect to the server using ssh command as below.

```
ssh komz-admin@pxxxxxxx04.corp.xxx.net
sudo -u xxx_bio_xxx -i
```

Comment: If `scp` is giving `Timeout` , first that has to be fixed! Check `ConnectTimeout` parameter in ssh config! It could also be that the remote server is not reachable.

Comment: Can you specify more? Where you start the scp command, on the prod server or on the dev server? (please copy&paste the ommand as well) And when it gives you timeout? It can not start the copy or starts the copy, but runs into timeout later?

Comment: i am sorry i am new to linux. how to find out wat unix i am using. how can i check the ConnectTimeout

Comment: i did scp command from prod.

Comment: `[sys_bio_tern@prod05 tmp]$ scp /tmp/sbg.snappy komz-admin@dev01.corp.xxx.net:/tmp
ssh: connect to host dev01.corp.xxx.net port 22: Connection timed out
lost connection`

Comment: @komz OS Name- `cat /proc/version ` , run this command: `scp -vvv /tmp/sbg.snappy komz-admin@dev01.corp.xxx.net:/tmp`, this will give info about the problem. Update the Question with these outputs.

Comment: Also run `ping <dev_server_ip>` command from prod to the other server! This would tell you about the connectivity!

Comment: You can also run `ping dev01.corp.xxx.net`

Comment: scp is based on SSH, that would mean that you could not even connect by SSH, are you able?

Comment: @saisasanka i m getting this output for -vvv .  `Executing: program /usr/bin/ssh host dev01.corp.xxx.net, user komz-admin, command scp -v -t /tmp
OpenSSH_5.3p1, OpenSSL 1.0.1e-fips 11 Feb 2013
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: Applying options for *
debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to dev01.corp.xxx.net [10.142.128.51] port 22.
debug1: connect to address 10.142.128.51 port 22: Connection timed out
ssh: connect to host dev01.corp.xxx.net port 22: Connection timed out
lost connection`

Answer (score 2):

Looks like your prod server can't reach the dev server (on ssh). I assume you can reach both from your workstation. You can use scp 3 hosts copy, which copies between hosts using a 3rd one (in your case prod05 -> workstation -> dev 01). Of course it's not the fastest way to copy, both perfect when you have to copy once and you have firewall issues.

Run the following on your workstation (where you can reach both):

```
scp -3 prod05:/tmp/sbg.snappy admin@dev01.corp.xxx.net:/tmp
```

From the man page of scp:

```
 -3      Copies between two remote hosts are transferred through the local host.
         Without this option the data is copied directly between the two
         remote hosts.  Note that this option disables the progress meter.
```

Comment: `scp: illegal option -- 3` getting this error

Answer (score -1):

First, check ssh connectivity from production to DEV server. If it is ok then do following steps,

Use RSYNC utility for file transfer,

Example:

```
rsync -avz "source filename" user@x.x.x.x:"destination path"
```

And if ssh connectivity fails, then check logs and print output here

Comment: If scp is giving Timeout , first that has to be fixed!  As `man rsync` says `For remote transfers, a modern rsync uses ssh for its communications` unless otherwise modified. So `ConnectTimeout` parameter is critical. It could also be that the remote host is not reachable. Its just not that the `scp` failed but `rsync`  is going to work.

Comment: @Syed Abdul Qadeer how to check connectivity from prod to server

Comment: how to capture ssh logs. i am not getting any logs.

Comment: just perform ssh root@<ip address>